# Gnome-Desktop Graphics Freeze when Interacting with the Mouse

Tags: gnome, mouse, freeze

Recently some of my applications freeze graphically when interacting with the mouse.

Applications:
Gnome-Terminal, Gnome-Calendar, Gnome-Mines, Nautilus, Terminator
(Seems like anything gnome related or perhaps using the same libraries as gnome)

Symptoms:
The terminal graphics freeze, background image is frozen in terminal window (you can tell when resizing), when interacting with the mouse.

So far this is what I've noticed:

1. xterm, FireFox, etc. do not have this problem.
2. Terminal is still working. I can type commands and execute them with no problem although I can't see what I'm typing. Same applies to other applications, e.g., Nautilus still launches the application to open a file if I press enter while selected.
3. Terminal is still accepting interrupt signals and keyboard shortcuts.
4. Whether or not the application has focus does not matter.
5. The mouse does not need to move. Even if resizing the terminal window causes it to overlap with the mouse pointer it freezes.
6. I have not noticed this problem with any other application.

Comment: Could be issues with the graphics card. It may be wise to post system information (use "edit" to add relevant info to your question)